# How to sum all values for numbers in rows in a file

Tags: python-3.x, list, sum, python-import

I am creating a program which involves summing all numbers in  the rows of a .txt file. The file is randomly generated, and consists of 100 random numbers, each occupying their own row. What I would like to do is create a list of all the numbers in the rows and then take the sum of that list. For some reason, the code I have is not working:

```
import os
import math

filename = input("Enter file name: ")
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    print(filename, "does not exist")
else:
    fin = open(filename)
    counter = -1
    comments = 0
    total = 0

    for line in fin:
        if "#" in line:
            comments += 1
        counter = counter + 1

    newlist = [[]]
    fin = open(filename)

    for line in fin:
        newlist = [[]]
        val = []
        for value in line:
            val.append(value)
        newList.append(val)
        total = sum(newList)


    print("Count:", counter)
    print("Comments:", comments)
    print("Total:", total)
```

The top part runs fine, but the function for the "total" value (the sum which I am trying to derive) is not working. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a line of *numbers* separated by whitespace (as opposed to digits not separated), your dual `for` loop is not going to work as you think:

```
>>> line = '12 34 56 78 90'
>>> for value in line: print(value)
... 
1
2

3
4

5
6

7
8

9
0
```

As per above, iterating over a string (such as the line you input) will process it one *character* at a time.

To process whitespace-separated *words* in a string, you can use something like:

```
>>> for value in line.split(): print(int(value))
... 
12
34
56
78
90
```

You'll also want to turn them into integers (as shown) if you want to sum them.

Comment: This is helpful, but basically I don't want to print the list itself, but rather *create* the list out of the numbers in the rows of the file, then sum that list and print the "total" variable for the sum.

Comment: @duder: then you replace my `print` with whatever processing you need (your `append`, for example). My intent was just to show what processing of a string does in the context of the `for` loop, handling individual characters (what's going wrong) rather than whitespace-separated numbers (what you need).

Comment: @duder: glad I could help. Cheers.